# How to convert "." to "_" on a web page, in HTML

Tags: html, data-conversion

Kind of a weird question, but I kind of need it for a time sensitive fix to a site.

I have a lot of data that has a period "." that marks data on a site. And I would like to possibly change this in the site to possibly be a underscore "_".

I can't touch the data itself, because it is sensitive data that is synchronized with other data locations.

Now, I want to know, is there an HTML code, that would just change how the data appeared on the website? Is there a line of code that I can input that will convert all periods and make them look like underscores for that page?

I've been searching all over, but Google can't get past converting Unicode T_T...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank You

Comment: HTML is not a scripting language. If you cannot touch the data server side (say with PHP or Python, or whatever), you will have to use JavaScript on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Javascript/jQuery function to change what the page says, without it actually changing the data serverside:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bodyText = $('#data').text(); //assuming this is where the text is you want to change
    bodyText = bodyText.replace(/\./g,"_");
    $('#data').text(bodyText);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CFZ8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to manipulate data, something HTML isn't designed to do. You might have to buckle down and learn some php if you want to start replacing a string with a different string. The function would look something like this:

```
echo str_replace('.','_',$data);
```

Comment: You are correct, HTML does not perform logic as it is a markup language.  No need to "think" if you know something =)

Answer (score 0):

SomekidwithHTML has the right idea. Just a little off because replace doesn't actually replace the variable, it just returns the new string.

hillsons is correct. You need to use JavaScript to parse it on the client side if you cannot touch the data on the server side.

```
var bodyText = $('body').html(); //assuming this is where the text is you want to change
bodyText = bodyText.replace(/\./g,"_");
$('body').html(bodyText);​​
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/paV2R/

Comment: by using `.html()`, wouldn't there be a problem with the markup if an `alt` attribute or a `title` attribute had a period in it? An image's source? An `<a>` element's href if it had a file extension? Better idea to use `.text()`, so everything doesn't get messed up.

Comment: @SomekidwithHTML You are correct with that. I ought to have used .`text()` rather than .`html()`. I would suggest you to change your fiddle so you use a regex instead of looking through the string several times as the number of periods grows, performance will falter.